# How to trigger jenkins every time a repository is created on github org?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I know how to trigger jenkins if a push is made to a repo but for this instance, I have a github organization and want to trigger jenkins when a repository is made on this github organization (to add webhooks and teams). I have an org-level hook but there isn't a place to specify a trigger. The git plugin specifically asks for a repository url.

I was going to create a repo that gets updated with list of repositories and have that repo as the hook but that sounds over-engineered. Any other easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Organization webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/hooks/) ([introduced in December 2014](https://github.com/blog/1933-introducing-organization-webhooks)) can be made for any [events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/), including [creation events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#createevent) (which include repository creation)

You should be able to register one, with a Jenkins server URL as listener. Since the Jenkins GitHub plugin might not process your exact webjook JSON payload, that URL could be one of a custom listener, able to notify your Jenkins.
See for instance [`worg/hookah`](https://github.com/worg/hookah).

Comment: I understand the org webhooks but the problem is when I want to trigger it, jenkins accepts a repo url vs I want to trigger on the org level.

Comment: @tyrell_c the idea is not to use a Jenkins plugins (which accepts only repo url anyway), but a custom listener like https://github.com/worg/hookah which will then trigger the right Jenkins jobs.